How do assembly reference version numbers work?
How are reference version numbers (i.e. minor version numbers) interpreted by .NET?
I have a reference to Newtonsoft.Json (for example) 13.0.3 in my project (library). However if I compile this and view the library in .NET reflector, it shows the reference to 13.0.0.0. This works fine when running, if Newtonsoft.Json v13.0.3 is in the same directory as my library.
Then due to a bit of tom-foolery with obfuscation & smartassembly, another library incorrectly ended up with a reference to 13.0.1 (viewed from .NET Reflector) - this does not work with 13.0.3, understandably. If I add this binding redirect:
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-13.0.3.0" newVersion="13.0.3.0" />
... it still gives an exception saying it can't load v13.0.3, even though 13.0.3 is there! But if I change it to this:
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-14.0.0.0" newVersion="13.0.0.0" />
... it works fine even though 13.0.0 is not there! (it's 13.0.3)
So my question is, would I be correct in the assumptions that

a reference to version x.0.0.0 will work with any dll of version x.y.z ?
When building an application in Visual Studio, if add a reference to a dll of version x.y.z it will "reset" it when building to x.0.0.0 ?
Binding redirects can't be used to redirect from one specific minor version to another?

... and if not, how does it work?

"13.0.3" is the semantic version number.  The CLR knows nothing about it, it is up to the library author to keep it in sync with the [AssemblyVersion].  Afaik, NewtonSoft's practice is to publish an x.y.z semantic version as a x.0.0.0 assembly version.  In other words, any revision of a major version is backwards compatible.  That doesn't quite explain the problem you had however.  You are not alone, quacks like a mistake.

Checking, I don't see the mistake.  13.0.1 and 13.0.3 are both assembly version 13.0.0.0.  Hmm.  Sounds like you did have a 12.0 reference.
